# Python switch-case unexpectedly executing all cases

Tags: python, switch-statement, python-3.7

## Original post (edit/update below:)

I'm trying to create a switch-case function in Python to avoid a really long if:elseif:elseif:elseif...else statement (running 3.7 so don't have 3.10's match-case statements). So, I'm toying with this dictionary-lookup instead (which for the purposes of this example has been kept deliberately short).

I've already defined a similar function elsewhere in the program, and it works as expected. However, the new switch-case function is supposed to call other functions in response to the provided input (the other lookup I have simply returns a value). Curiously, it executes every case instead of just the one required. And, I don't understand why.

```py
# switcher.py
# optional cli args: ipaddress, port

def config_updater(k, v):
    print(f'config_update(k,v): {k, v}')  # Sanity check
    switcher = {
        'ipaddress': update_ip(v),
        'port': update_port(v)
    }

    return switcher.get(k)


def update_ip(a):
    global host_ip
    host_ip = a
    print(f'update_ip: host_ip updated to {a}')


def update_port(b):
    global host_port
    host_port = b
    print(f'update_port: host_port updated to {b}')

#
# Code for command line argparse functionality goes here
# Essentially, arguments (ipaddress, port) can be optionally added at command line
#

args = parser.parse_args()
dargs = vars(args)  # Creates a dictionary of command line arguments and their values

# Setting default values if no arguments added at command line
global host_ip, host_port
host_ip = 'localhost'
host_port = 4840
i = 1  # For loop counter

for field, value in dargs.items():
    print(f'\n\nFor loop iteration: {i}\n')  # Sanity check
    i += 1
    print(f'Printing current field-value pair: {field}, {value}\n')  # Sanity check
    if value is not None:
        config_updater(field, value)

print(f'\n\nPrinting final statement:')
print(f'IP address: {host_ip}')
print(f'Port: {host_port}')
```

Now, when this is run like so:

```
$ python3 switcher.py -ip 192.168.0.28 -p 2228
```

I get the following output, which runs update_ip and update_port for both arguments instead of just for their respective lookups.

```
For loop iteration: 1

Printing current field-value pair: ipaddress, 192.168.0.28

config_update(k,v): ('ipaddress', '192.168.0.28')
update_ip: host_ip updated to 192.168.0.28
update_port: host_port updated to 192.168.0.28


For loop iteration: 2

Printing current field-value pair: port, 2228

config_update(k,v): ('port', '2228')
update_ip: host_ip updated to 2228
update_port: host_port updated to 2228


Printing final statement:
IP address: 2228
Port: 2228
```

To clarify, I'm expecting the output to be:

```
For loop iteration: 1

Printing current field-value pair: ipaddress, 192.168.0.28

config_update(k,v): ('ipaddress', '192.168.0.28')
update_ip: host_ip updated to 192.168.0.28


For loop iteration: 2

Printing current field-value pair: port, 2228

config_update(k,v): ('port', '2228')
update_port: host_port updated to 2228


Printing final statement:
IP address: 192.168.0.28
Port: 2228
```

Have I fundamentally misunderstood how these lookups can be used to call other functions?

## EDIT (based on marked answer and comments):

My revised code continues to use the dictionary lookup - inline with the original question - but has been adjusted to make use of the already available global argsparser variables, and now looks like this:

```py
# switcher.py
# optional cli args: ipaddress, port

def get_default_config(field):
    switcher = {
        'ipaddress': set_default_ip,
        'port': set_default_port
    }
    func_to_use = switcher.get(field)
    if func_to_use:
        return func_to_use()


def set_default_ip():
    args.ipaddress = 'localhost'
    print(f'update_ip: host_ip updated to {args.ipaddress}')


def set_default_port():
    args.port = 4840
    print(f'update_port: host_port updated to {args.port}')

#
# Code for command line argparse functionality goes here
# Essentially, arguments (ipaddress, port) can be optionally added at command line
#

args = parser.parse_args()
dargs = vars(args)

for field, value in dargs.items():
    if value is None:
        get_default_config(field)

print('\n\n')
print(f'IP address set to: {args.ipaddress}')
print(f'Port set to: {args.port}')
```

Thanks to everyone that contributed!

Comment: `update_ip(v)` directly calls "update_ip" during dictionary creation. Use function object `update_ip` only as dict value and return `switcher.get(k)(v)`. Same for the port.

Comment: This whole thing looks grossly overengineered. You already have globally-accessible  expressions for the IP address and the port: `args.ipaddress` and `args.port`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher That does, indeed, fix the problem. And I understand the difference too. Thank you.

Comment: @chepner I agree that it's a little over the top, perhaps. Especially in this very short example. A couple of if statements checking if the args.ipaddress and args.port value is not set to None would do the same job and likely be more readable. But, honestly, I've always disliked longer if:elif statements and found them to be unwieldy and this was a short example just as a proof of concept, I suppose. Admittedly, with 3.10 having the match-case built-in function anyway I can't imagine I'll use this very often.

Comment: Who said anything about `if` statements? I'm saying you don't need new global variables (and all the machinery set up to set them) when you can just use `args.ipaddress` and `args.port` directly. There's very little difference between a function needing to know the global name `args` vs having to know the global names `ipaddress` and `port`.

Comment: I obviously misinterpreted your "over engineered" statement extending it to the lookup vs. if statements. But, I've already taken your argument into account as I'm using the args globals instead of creating my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the dictionary like so

```
switcher = {
        'ipaddress': update_ip(v),
        'port': update_port(v)
    }
```

you *call* the functions and the returned value from those functions is assigned to that key of the dictionary.

Instead, you want to assign the functions themselves as the values in the dictionary, and call them later when you know which one you want.

```
switcher = {
        'ipaddress': update_ip,
        'port': update_port
    }
func_to_use = switcher.get(k)
if func_to_use:
    return func_to_use(v)
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand the problem here (i.e., building the dictionary and calling the function at the same time, as I had passed it parameters). This did the trick.